# Can't find Modernizr.load() or HTML5 audio on https://modernizr.com/download

Tags: html, audio, modernizr

In the book [Build an HTML5 Game](https://www.nostarch.com/html5game) on page 17, it asks to add the library Modernizr with the following feature detections:

- CSS Transitions
- Canvas
- HTML5 Audio
- Modernizr.load()
- Modernizr.prefixed()

I couldn't find Modernizr.load() and HTML5 Audio. Also [the builder looked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WUEp.jpg) different that what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The component you are looking for is `Web Audio API`.

<s>Also, the function `Modernizr.load()` is included in all Modernizr packages by default.</s>

For the `Modernizr.load()` method, sorry for the confusion.

The `Modernizr.load()` [is not included anymore](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1401), as it was essentially another library named `yepnope.js`. And then, the `yepnope.js` library was deprecated, because [the developers felt that its use had run its course](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js#deprecation-notice).

> The authors of yepnope feel that the front-end community now offers
>   better software for loading scripts, as well as conditionally loading
>   scripts.

The documentation of `yepnope.js` [is still online](http://yepnopejs.com/). I would recommend reading it, as well as [Modernizr's documentation](https://modernizr.com/docs), in order to understand what `Modernizr.load()` was supposed to do and come up with another solution.

Comment: Hmmm when I tried to use Modernizr.load() it said that there was no function do you know what could be causing that. Also I tried it off my iPod 6 and on a different browser to, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, you can't download Modernizr with the function Modernizr.load(). Although, you can download all files, scripts, and more from the book at https://nostarch.com/html5game by clicking on 'Download source code [...]', just below the 'Contents | Reviews' buttons. In the ZIP directory just downloaded, you will be able to find the old Modernizr module **containing Modernizr.load()** in C:\Users*user*\Downloads\Build an HTML5 Game Source Files\Build an HTML5 Game Source Files\Chapter_1.zip\Chapter_1_js. It is named modernizr.js and normally, you should be able to work with it.